# How do I change the color of a specific printed letter in python?

Tags: python, colors

I am trying to make a short quiz and I want to display Incorrect Answer in red.
Welcome to my Quiz!
Would you like to begin?: yes
Goodluck
What is the capital of France?:  france # random answer
***Incorrect Answer*** # i am trying to display it in red.

My code is:

```
print ("Welcome to my Quiz!")
begin = input("Would you like to begin?: ")
if begin == ("yes")  or begin == ("Yes"):
print ("Goodluck")
Q1 = input("What is the capital of France?:  ")
if Q1 == ("Paris") or Q1 == ("paris"):
    print ("Correct Answer!")
    print (" ")
else:
    print ("Incorrect Answer")
    print (" ")

Q2 = input("What is the capital of India?:  ")
if Q2 == ("New Delhi") or Q2 == ("new delhi"):
    print ("Correct Answer!")
    print (" ")
else:
    print ("Incorrect Answer")
    print (" ")

else:
    print ("Goodbye :)")
```

Comment: This isn't related to python but to whatever you're printing in (GUI window, terminal...)

Comment: Indeed. Of course `print()` often goes to a terminal but even then it can depend on which terminal is being used.

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, thats possible:

```
print('\033[31m' + "Incorrect Answer" +'\033[0m')
```

Here some more colors:

```
# Regular Colors
Black="\[\033[0;30m\]"        # Black
Red="\[\033[0;31m\]"          # Red
Green="\[\033[0;32m\]"        # Green
Yellow="\[\033[0;33m\]"       # Yellow
Blue="\[\033[0;34m\]"         # Blue
Purple="\[\033[0;35m\]"       # Purple
Cyan="\[\033[0;36m\]"         # Cyan
White="\[\033[0;37m\]"        # White

# Bold
BBlack="\[\033[1;30m\]"       # Black
BRed="\[\033[1;31m\]"         # Red
BGreen="\[\033[1;32m\]"       # Green
BYellow="\[\033[1;33m\]"      # Yellow
BBlue="\[\033[1;34m\]"        # Blue
BPurple="\[\033[1;35m\]"      # Purple
BCyan="\[\033[1;36m\]"        # Cyan
BWhite="\[\033[1;37m\]"       # White

# Underline
UBlack="\[\033[4;30m\]"       # Black
URed="\[\033[4;31m\]"         # Red
UGreen="\[\033[4;32m\]"       # Green
UYellow="\[\033[4;33m\]"      # Yellow
UBlue="\[\033[4;34m\]"        # Blue
UPurple="\[\033[4;35m\]"      # Purple
UCyan="\[\033[4;36m\]"        # Cyan
UWhite="\[\033[4;37m\]"       # White

# Background
On_Black="\[\033[40m\]"       # Black
On_Red="\[\033[41m\]"         # Red
On_Green="\[\033[42m\]"       # Green
On_Yellow="\[\033[43m\]"      # Yellow
On_Blue="\[\033[44m\]"        # Blue
On_Purple="\[\033[45m\]"      # Purple
On_Cyan="\[\033[46m\]"        # Cyan
On_White="\[\033[47m\]"       # White

# High Intensty
IBlack="\[\033[0;90m\]"       # Black
IRed="\[\033[0;91m\]"         # Red
IGreen="\[\033[0;92m\]"       # Green
IYellow="\[\033[0;93m\]"      # Yellow
IBlue="\[\033[0;94m\]"        # Blue
IPurple="\[\033[0;95m\]"      # Purple
ICyan="\[\033[0;96m\]"        # Cyan
IWhite="\[\033[0;97m\]"       # White

# Bold High Intensty
BIBlack="\[\033[1;90m\]"      # Black
BIRed="\[\033[1;91m\]"        # Red
BIGreen="\[\033[1;92m\]"      # Green
BIYellow="\[\033[1;93m\]"     # Yellow
BIBlue="\[\033[1;94m\]"       # Blue
BIPurple="\[\033[1;95m\]"     # Purple
BICyan="\[\033[1;96m\]"       # Cyan
BIWhite="\[\033[1;97m\]"      # White

# High Intensty backgrounds
On_IBlack="\[\033[0;100m\]"   # Black
On_IRed="\[\033[0;101m\]"     # Red
On_IGreen="\[\033[0;102m\]"   # Green
On_IYellow="\[\033[0;103m\]"  # Yellow
On_IBlue="\[\033[0;104m\]"    # Blue
On_IPurple="\[\033[10;95m\]"  # Purple
On_ICyan="\[\033[0;106m\]"    # Cyan
On_IWhite="\[\033[0;107m\]"   # White
```

source: https://gist.github.com/vratiu/9780109

---

note: in the additional list, colors are formated for another language. To is on python "[" and "[\" have to be removed from the start and the end.

Comment: Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 2):

YOu need to include termcolor as follows:

```
from termcolor import colored
```

and then the specific print line as follows:

```
print( colored( "Incorrect Answer", "red" ) )
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me